# bootstrap 4 nav-tabs highlight active state

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem having my nav-tabs active state from switching when i click other options. it's working in bootstrap 3 but i've use bootstrap 4 . now it's not working

**here's my tabs.**
[image]

here's my html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs animation" role="tablist" >


                                                <li class="active" ><a href="#cars" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cars</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#vans" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Vans & Pickup</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#suv" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SUVs & Crossover</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#mpv" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">MPVs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#hybrid" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Hybrid</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#performance" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Performance</a></li>
                                    </ul>
```

and my css that's working in bootstrap 3:

```
.nav-tabs > li > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;

}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:active {
  background: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: default;
  border: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 15px 14px 15px;
}

.nav-tabs>li >a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: white;

}
```

> .nav-tabs>li.active>a:after

thats where i got those line below and that need to switch when click other tabs.

Comment: Did you port your code from v3 to v4 or just simply copy-paste it and use v4 libs? There are many significant changes in navbars & navtabs in v4.X.

Comment: copied and paste it.

Comment: got it now thanks!